# The difference between const T& and T in function return

Tags: c++, constants, return-value

I am confused with const T& and T in function return.

For example, I have a class A:

```
class A {
  private:
    vector<T> my_vector_;
  public:
    T fun1() {
      return my_vector_.at(0);
    }
    const T& fun2() {
      return my_vector_.at(0);
    }
}
```

Then,

```
Class A a;
T b = a.fun1();
const T& c = a.fun1();
const T& d = a.fun2();
```

What's the difference for these three case? Thank you.

Comment: You will be able to assign a different value to `b` later in the program, but `c` and `d` are both references to const so they can't be modified. I'm not sure if this what you are asking, your question is slightly vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
T b = a.fun1();
```

Here, `b` holds a **copy** of the element at position 0 of the `vector`. Meaning, any modification made to the former won't affect the latter.

```
const T& c = a.fun1();
```

`fun1` returned an object by value, and you've used a reference to `const` to refer to it. Taking this into account, the object is really "floating in space". Its lifetime will be bound to that of `c`, but is't still a copy of the original from the `vector`.

```
const T& d = a.fun2();
```

`fun2` returned a reference to `const` to an element inside of the `vector`, and you bound `d` to it. From now on, the latter is an alias to the former.

Comment: Thanks faranwath. I am a little bit confused with the second case. In that case, c refers to a copy of the element at position 0 of the vector. So if I remove the const restriction, it should work almost the same as the first case, is this right? Do they have any difference in memory allocation (I think both of them are on stack and the lifetime are bound to the outer function)?

Comment: *So if I remove the const restriction, it should work almost the same as the first case, is this right?* No, and for good reason. Given that the object is a temporary, any modification to it would be useless, because normally you won't be able to get your hands on it. For instance, if a function `foo` receives an `A` by reference to non-`const`, and you invoke it like `foo(A{})`, then any change made to the object inside of the function will be lost as soon as it returns. Given that the type of the argument is `A&`, you'd normally assume any change would endure.

Answer (score 1):

When you return an object by reference (i.e. `T& fun(...) { ...}`) then you are returning the same object that you were using inside your function, while when you return the object by value (i.e. `T fun(...) { ...}`) the object is copied before returning the function.

You can check this if you print your object's memory address inside the function and after it has been returned:

```
printf("%p\n", &my_object);
```

The `const` only says that the compiler should make sure you are not modifying the object from the outside (i.e. you cannot do: `object.field = value`).

I have arranged this sample that shows all the differences between those approches:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class X {
    public:
        int i;

        X();
        X(const X&);
};

// Copy constructor
X::X(const X& x) {
    printf("Copy constructor invoked\n");
}

// Default constructor
X::X() : i(0) {
    printf("Creating a object\n");
}

X my_fun_1(X& x) { return x; }
X& my_fun_2(X& x) { return x; }
const X& my_fun_3(X& x) { return x; }

int main () {
    X x0;

    printf("\nInvoke my_fun_1\n");
    X x1 = my_fun_1(x0);

    printf("\nInvoke my_fun_2\n");
    X& x2 = my_fun_2(x0);

    printf("\nInvoke my_fun_3\n");
    const X& x3 = my_fun_3(x0);

    printf("\nResults:\n");
    printf("x0 => %p\n", &x0);
    printf("x1 => %p\n", &x1);
    printf("x2 => %p\n", &x2);
    printf("x3 => %p\n", &x3);

    x0.i = 1;
    x1.i = 1;
    x2.i = 1;
    //Compile-time error: x3.i = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run it, the output should be:

```
$ g++ a.cpp && ./a.out
Creating a object

Invoke my_fun_1
Copy constructor invoked

Invoke my_fun_2

Invoke my_fun_3

Results:
x0 => 0x7fff8710cce0
x1 => 0x7fff8710ccf0
x2 => 0x7fff8710cce0
x3 => 0x7fff8710cce0
```

Notice:

- If you don't use `&` then the copy constructor is used
- If you use `const` then modifying the returned object using that reference is a compile-time error.

Comment: Thank you for your nice reply! But what confused me most is something like X& x4 = my_fun_1(x0). faranwath gives a nice explanation above, but thank you all the same.